# Can pydub set the maximum/minimum volume?

Tags: python, audio, limit, volume, pydub

As title, can I set a value for maximum/minimum volume, that is, there won't be too loud or too quiet in output audio file? (Not normalize, I just want tune the specific volume to normal, as the photo below.)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I do, and it works well for me. The shortcoming is the bad performance if the sample_rate is too small.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.utils import make_chunks

def match_target_amplitude(sound, target_dBFS):
    change_in_dBFS = target_dBFS - sound.dBFS
    return sound.apply_gain(change_in_dBFS)

def sound_slice_normalize(sound, sample_rate, target_dBFS):
    def max_min_volume(min, max):
        for chunk in make_chunks(sound, sample_rate):
            if chunk.dBFS < min:
                yield match_target_amplitude(chunk, min)
            elif chunk.dBFS > max:
                yield match_target_amplitude(chunk, max)
            else:
                yield chunk

    return reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, max_min_volume(target_dBFS[0], target_dBFS[1]))

sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3("vanilla_sky.mp3")
normalized_db = min_normalized_db, max_normalized_db = [-32.0, -18.0]
sample_rate = 1000
normalized_sound = sound_slice_normalize(sound, sample_rate, normalized_db)
```

Comment: Try using the The ITU-R BS.1770-4 standard 's integrated loudness algorithm, which computes the loudness by breaking down the audio signal into 0.4-second segments with 75% overlap. Here's a python implementation https://github.com/BrechtDeMan/loudness.py

Answer (score 4):

[Loudness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loudness) is a little complicated - a simple solution is to measure using one of the simpler methods like dBFS and set the gain on all your audio to match.

```
sounds = [audio_segment1, audio_segment2, audio_segment3, audio_segment4]

def set_loudness(sound, target_dBFS):
    loudness_difference = target_dBFS - sound.dBFS
    return sound.apply_gain(loudness_difference)

# -20dBFS is relatively quiet, but very likely to be enough headroom    
same_loudness_sounds = [
    set_loudness(sound, target_dBFS=-20)
    for sound in sounds
]
```

One complicating factor is that some of your sounds may have extended portions of silence, or even just very quiet parts. That would pull down the average, and you may have to write a more sophisticated loudness measurement. Again, a simple way, you can slice the sound into shorter pieces and simply use the loudest one assuming your whole sound is 15 minutes long, we can take 1 minute slices:

```
from pydub.utils import make_chunks

def get_loudness(sound, slice_size=60*1000):
    return max(chunk.dBFS for chunk in make_chunks(sound, slice_size))


# ...and replace set_loudness() in above example with…
def set_loudness(sound, target_dBFS):
    loudness_difference = target_dBFS - get_loudness(sound)
    return sound.apply_gain(loudness_difference)
```

Comment: @Jiarro this method seems lead to too loud or too quiet if the max/min is far away from average as you choose the extreme value to be the criterion of the adjustment. (It will also increase the other part which is not too quiet or decrease the other part which is not too loud)

Comment: @LeoHsieh like I said, loudness is a complicated thing to measure - I'm just giving you some strategies to pursue. The second example shows a way to use the loudest 1 minute chunk to avoid averaging in silence (you can play with that value, maybe 15 second chunks would work better). Another issue not mentioned above is that not all frequencies sound equally loud at the same power (see fletcher-munson curves). You may also want to consider using the median loudness of the chunks instead of the max with shorter chunk lengths.

Comment: @Jiarro Ok I see. I will try shorter chunk lengths to achieve my goal, although it may take lot's of time to do so... Thx for your help.