# How to set a fix volume throughout an audio file using Python

Tags: python, audio-processing, pydub

I've some audio clips each around 5 minutes long. Within each audio file, 2 people are talking,
where some part is loud (when person 1 is talking) while some part is very low (difficult to hear, while person 2 is talking). I've tried using #**pydub**, also tried **"pydub.effects"** **normalize** too, but nothing seems working. Any idea what will work, and how I should proceed on this matter?

Here's the link which I followed
[Can pydub set the maximum/minimum volume?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720395/can-pydub-set-the-maximum-minimum-volume)

Comment: Have you tried searching for and applying tools for Automatic Gain Control?

Comment: Yes, I've tried Audacity. But it's still not amplified to the level of working. @Jon Nordby

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You need to provide some example audio, and the expected results, if you want anyone to be able to tackle this.